# pandas tzinfo lost by combine_first

Tags: python, pandas

I realized that some of my dataframes are missing tzinfo, and determined that combine_first is dropping it. I set up a short example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['UTCdatetime','abc'],
                  data=pd.to_datetime('20100101 01:01').tz_localize('UTC'),
                  index=pd.date_range('20140627', periods=1))
print(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['UTCdatetime','xyz'],
                  data=pd.to_datetime('20121212 12:12').tz_localize('UTC'),
                  index=pd.date_range('20140628', periods=1))
print(df2)
df1 = df2[['UTCdatetime']].combine_first(df1)
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
                          UTCdatetime                        abc
2014-06-27  2010-01-01 01:01:00+00:00  2010-01-01 01:01:00+00:00
                          UTCdatetime                        xyz
2014-06-28  2012-12-12 12:12:00+00:00  2012-12-12 12:12:00+00:00
                   UTCdatetime                        abc
2014-06-27 2010-01-01 01:01:00  2010-01-01 01:01:00+00:00
2014-06-28 2012-12-12 12:12:00                        NaN
```

Prior to combine_first, the datetimes all show UTC. However once I do combine_first, +00:00 (e.g. UTC) is missing, although the times themselves are fine.

I'm using pandas 0.14.0. Is there any way to avoid losing tzinfo?

On a related note, is there an easy way to programmatically tell if the tzinfo is there? Doing tz_localize raises an exception if it's already there, and tz_convert raises an exception if it's not. Thanks!

Comment: hmm, this looks like a bug, see here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7630

Comment: Thanks Jeff. 
Very ugly, but I was able to replace the functionality I needed by using `df1.ix[df2.index,'UTCdatetime'] = df2.ix[df2.index,'UTCdatetime']` after first combining the indices into df1.index.