# pandas: how to write tz-aware datetime columns with some missing data to store

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframes with columns of timezone-aware datetimes that I need to write to a store. However as soon as I have any missing values, writing fails. I set up a simple example:

```
pd.set_option('io.hdf.default_format','table')
mdstore = pd.HDFStore(storeFile, complevel=9, complib='blosc')
utcdate = pd.to_datetime('20000101', utc=True)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['UTCdatetime'], data=utcdate, index=pd.date_range('20140627', periods=2))
mdstore['/Test'] = df1
```

This works fine, as it has no missing values. If I introduce missing values though I get one of two different errors.

Error 1: If I then add another column with only one of the two rows populated, I get an error:

```
df1.loc['20140628','UTCdatetime2'] = utcdate
print(df1)
mdstore['/Test'] = df1
                      UTCdatetime               UTCdatetime2
2014-06-27  2000-01-01 00:00:00+00:00                        NaN
2014-06-28  2000-01-01 00:00:00+00:00  2000-01-01 00:00:00+00:00

Exception: cannot find the correct atom type -> [dtype->object,items->Index([u'UTCdatetime', u'UTCdatetime2'], dtype='object')] 'float' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'
```

Error 2: If instead I add a new row with NA populated I get a different error:

```
df1.loc[pd.to_datetime('20140629'),'UTCdatetime'] = pd.NaT
print(df1)
mdstore['/Test'] = df1
                      UTCdatetime
2014-06-27  2000-01-01 00:00:00+00:00
2014-06-28  2000-01-01 00:00:00+00:00
2014-06-29                        NaN

TypeError: too many timezones in this block, create separate data columns
```

I'm hoping for a workaround that doesn't involve filling the NaN's with an arbitrary date. I tried `fillna` with `pd.NaT` but that didn't do anything. Thanks!

PS I also had an issue with combine_first and tz ([pandas tzinfo lost by combine_first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502838)) - doesn't appear to be related but just in case.

Comment: For now I've broken down and started to save the datetimes as strings.. Graceful no, simple yes.

Comment: you can try to use the ``table`` format for this. Generally pandas is not well tested for mixed timezones in a column at all, or missing values with datetimes that have timezones. Welcome more test coverage for these. That said for ``datetime64[ns]`` works really well with missing values. Usually If I needed to do something like this, I would keep a separate column of 'tz' info.